# Terraformed private GKE cluster automation access

Tags: networking, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have terraformed (Terraform version 11.10) a private Kubernetes cluster on the Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) using the following `.tf`:

```
module "nat" {
  source     = "GoogleCloudPlatform/nat-gateway/google"
  region     = "europe-west1"
  network    = "default"
  subnetwork = "default"
}

resource "google_container_node_pool" "cluster_1_np" {
  name               = "cluster-1-np"
  region             = "europe-west1"
  cluster            = "${google_container_cluster.cluster_1.name}"
  initial_node_count = 1

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = ["node_count"]
  }

  autoscaling {
    min_node_count = 1
    max_node_count = 50
  }

  management {
    auto_repair  = true
    auto_upgrade = true
  }

  node_config {
    oauth_scopes = [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub",
    ]

    tags = ["${module.nat.routing_tag_regional}"]
  }
}

resource "google_container_cluster" "cluster_1" {
  provider                 = "google-beta"
  name                     = "cluster-1"
  region                   = "europe-west1"
  remove_default_node_pool = true

  private_cluster_config {
    enable_private_endpoint = false
    enable_private_nodes    = true
    master_ipv4_cidr_block  = "172.16.0.0/28"
  }

  ip_allocation_policy {
    create_subnetwork = true
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = ["initial_node_count", "network_policy", "node_config", "node_pool"]
  }

  node_pool {
    name = "default-pool"
  }

  addons_config {
    http_load_balancing {
      disabled = false
    }

    horizontal_pod_autoscaling {
      disabled = false
    }
  }

  master_authorized_networks_config {
    cidr_blocks = [
      {
        cidr_block   = "<MY_OFFICE_CIDR>"
        display_name = "Office"
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

Which works great, giving me a private cluster (and the NAT works, giving the nodes access to the internet), and machines in my office can run `kubectl` commands to interact with it no bother.

The problem I now face is integrating any web-based Continuous Integration (CI) or Continuous Deployment (CD). Private clusters are a new feature of the Google Cloud Platform (GCP), and the documentation is a bit lacking in this area.

My attempts thus far have completely failed, my networking knowledge is simply insufficient. I tried [this solution](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/creating-kubernetes-engine-private-clusters-with-net-proxies) but it seems the automation machine must be on the same network as the proxy.

I found [this similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51944817/google-cloud-build-deploy-to-gke-private-cluster) (almost exactly the same but his is Cloud Build specific). In the comments to one of the answers of that question the OP mentions he found a workaround where he temporarily modifies the master authorized networks of the build machine but he has not stated exactly how he is carrying this out.

I attempted to replicate his workaround but the relevant `gcloud` commands seem to be able to `update` the list of networks, or completely remove all of them, not add/remove one at a time as his comment suggests.

Help from networking wizards would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common problem while interfacing with CI systems like [CircleCI](https://circleci.com/) or [Travis](https://travis-ci.org/) that live in the public cloud. You can use this command to update your `master authorized networks`

```
gcloud container clusters update [CLUSTER_NAME] \
  --enable-master-authorized-networks \
  --master-authorized-networks=<MY_OFFICE_CIDR>,<NEW-CIDR-FROM-CI> \
  --zone=<your-zone>
```

To remove the CI system network you can do something like this (just remove the network from the cli):

```
gcloud container clusters update [CLUSTER_NAME] \
  --enable-master-authorized-networks \
  --master-authorized-networks=<MY_OFFICE_CIDR> \
  --zone=<your-zone>
```

To completely remove all authorized networks (disable):

```
gcloud container clusters update [CLUSTER_NAME] \
  --no-enable-master-authorized-networks
```

You can also do it from the UI:

[image: authorized networks]

It's actually documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/authorized-networks).

Comment: Note that `--no-enable-master-authorized-networks` has the effect of allowing access from any IP, per the documentation linked in the answer.