# Configure Google Cloud Build to deploy to private GKE cluster via proxy

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-build

After I have [completed the steps required to set up access to a private GKE cluster via a proxy instance](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/creating-kubernetes-engine-private-clusters-with-net-proxies), how do I configure Google Cloud Build to deploy to the cluster via the proxy?

I'm looking for a solution that [will not require manipulating the cluster's authorized Master Networks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51944817/google-cloud-build-deploy-to-gke-private-cluster) beyond adding the IP address of the proxy server.